# Azure Website doesn't recognize my Database's Table after changing the Schema

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-roles

I have a Microsoft Azure Website running and working with an Azure SQL Database for the sole purpose of storing and retrieving user accounts. However I needed a mobile client as well there fore according to numerous tutorials online such as [THIS](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/using-existing-database-with-azure-mobile-services/), I had to change the 'schema' of the database's table from 'dbo' to my mobile service's name which is 'usermobileservice'.

This was done using the SQL query:

```
CREATE SCHEMA usermobileservice;
ALTER SCHEMA usermobileserviceTRANSFER dbo.usertable;
```

This did the trick and I was able to connect to the Database using my mobile applications BUT now I can't access the database using my Azure Website! Gives me this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid object name 'UserTable'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'UserTable'.
```

I believe the ASP.NET Web Application cannot find the Database Table anymore since I changed the schema? What is the right way of sharing the data between a Website and a Mobile Service?

Comment: That's because you changed the schema.  You'll need to update the web application queries to use `usermobileservice.UserTable`, or create an SQL Account that has `usermobileservice` as it's default schema and update the connection string to use this user.

Comment: Oh man! That explains a lot. Since making a brand new SQL is a hassle, how do I update the Web application queries sir? @BrendanGreen

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having the same issue, Just replace your SQL queries that call the table (where the schema was changed) with this:

> your_mobile_service_name.Your_Table_Name

In my case:

**usermobileservice.UserTable**

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM usermobileservice.UserTable
```

Thank you @Brendan Green for the directions!